# Amplifier with two-pole is unconditionally stable

Tags: amplifier, stability, oscillation, inverting-amplifier

This is from a lecture slide:

> 1. Amplifier with a single-pole is unconditionally stable.
> 2. Amplifier with two-pole is also unconditionally stable.

Are these properties considered for closed-loop transfer function of amplifier?
The maximum phase with one pole is 90 degree as frequency approaches infinity.
For negative feedback the maximum phase shift for No.1 is 270 degree and for No. 2 is 360 degree.
In this case, the No.2 is still unconditionally stable because the total phase shift is 360 only when frequency approaches infinity and this doesn't happen.
Am I understanding it right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. With 2 poles, the phase shift in the amplifier can approach 180 deg, and the gain will also asymptotically approach zero. Such a circuit is unconditionally stable with unity negative feedback.

An amplifier with any number of poles itself can be stable -- note that the 2 pole limitation is specifically for unity negative feedback.